# How do I view the IO priority of a process?

Tags: linux, io, scheduling, ionice, priority

How can I view the IO priority of a process? like to see for example if something has been `ionice`-ed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
ionice [-p] <pids/>
```

For example:

```
$ ionice -p `pidof X`
none: prio 0
```

This means `X` is using the `none` scheduling class (best effort) with priority 0 (highest priority out of 7). Read more with [`man ionice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice).