# iotop and ionice -p show a different class/priority for the same process

Tags: linux, io, proc, scheduling, ionice

After running
`ionice -c2 -n7 <PID>` on an I/O-intensive process (VirtualBox VM) and checking the result with `ionice -p <PID>` it shows `best-effort: prio 7` which is expected.

But when monitoring the overall disk I/O of all processes via `iotop` it shows in `PRIO` column a value of `be/4` for that process, which I assume means **b**est-**e**ffort and level (priority) 4, which is average priority and not expected.

Can somebody comment why there's a difference between what ionice and what iotop displays? And is there another way to verify the actual I/O priority of a given process other then with `ionice -p` ?

From what I understood, there's `/proc/<pid>/io` but it only displays bytes/characters read and written, but not the priority, cf. [Know which process does I/O without iotop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206260)
Also [How do I view the IO priority of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/how-do-i-view-the-io-priority-of-a-process) only lists `ionice -p`

For completeness sake, this is on RHEL 6.7 with iotop 0.3.2, and the scheduler is the default CFQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I already found part of the answer. By default `iotop` shows all processes and threads, and I usually run it via `iotop -o` which only shows threads and processes doing I/O. The VirtualBox process shown as `be/4` is actually a thread, and when I run `iotop -p <pid>` against the PID which I changed via `ionice` then it correctly displays `be/7` which is expected.

Would still be interesting to know why one thread of that process has a different I/O class/priority, but my ionice does not have `-P` option to change the I/O class/priority of a process group. Would be nice if someone knows a workaround/solution for that.

Comment: *"ionice does not have option to change process group. Would be nice if someone knows a workaround/solution for that."* 

**Use `ionice -p id1 id2 id3 ...`**

Comment: It was for Chrome in my case, I had to collect the PIDs using `ps`

Comment: I still wasn't able to change the io prority for threads, only for processes

Comment: @Codebling FWIW, the essential part in your quote was "my ionice" ... seems this was added back in 2014 according to util-linux changelog, hence -P probably wasn't available in RHEL 6.x - just adding for completeness sake

Comment: I saw and grokked that. I was suggesting an alternative, the use of lowercase `-p` with a list of PIDs grepped from `ps` instead of uppercase `-P` with a PGID. Even with my `ionice` which supports `-P`, PGID is not readily available information so it seems easier to always use a list of PIDs. Just through I'd mention it for posterity.

Comment: Was also wondering if you had found any addditional info on changing the ionice of threads, whose IO priority doesn't seem to change with the process'.